# Deleting lines with sed where the variable value is empty

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file which has data in the format
`A=1234

B=3456

C=5689`
Now sometimes there might not be variable values with the variables
i.e.
`A=1234

B=2566

C=

D=555`
I want to delete the lines in which there is nothing after "=".
What sed command can i use to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following sed should work:

```
sed -n '/= *$/!p' file
```

**EDIT:** To save these changes back to the file, use inline flag `-i`:

```
sed -i.bak -n '/= *$/!p' file
```

To delete blank lines with 0 or more spaces:

```
sed -i.bak -rn '/= *$|^ *$/!p' file
```

Comment: I would like to delete the lines from the file altogether.Your command just prints it without those lines.Do you know how to delete those lines from this file altogether? @anubhava

Comment: See the EDIT section. Basically: `sed -i.bak -n '/= *$/!p' file` will do the job.

Comment: One last point it deletes the line but spares the newlines and whitespaces anyway to fix that? @anubhava

Comment: Works like a charm thnx @anubhava

Answer (score 2):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk -F= '$2!=""' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line if there is nothing except possible whitespace after the `=`:

```
sed  '/=[ ]*$/d' input
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^[^=]*=\s*$/d' file
```

Comment: Works indeed but anubhava above has already solved the problem.But yours one also works thnx @potong